# How to convert the estimate from numbers to letters in a new column python

Tags: python

I want to print the average in letters (excellent, very good, good, acceptable) in a new column for each grade

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm having an error

Comment: then please add traceback of said error to your question

Comment: ValueError: Length of values (2901) does not match length of index (3263)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.